# Laptop wireless signal strength is low

Tags: wireless-networking

After spilled coffee on my keyboard, only the keyboard was damaged and it was replaced. However, my wireless signal is low and about 2-3 columns at most, also it can't pick up any connections around just the saved ones. I updated my driver, but nothing has changed. My brother's laptop which is in the same room can see more connections and has always 5 columns. Any idea what could  be the problem?

Laptop model: **Dell Inspirion N5110**

Comment: Was it working properly before? Would opening it up and checking the antenna connections be an option?

Comment: My bet is that when the keyboard was replaced, an antenna connection was dislodged.

Comment: Yes it worked properly before

Answer (score 1):

If you have the legacy drivers (original drivers from the manufacturers) there's most of time a hidden menu in it you can set the strenght of the signal and some others parameters, for that run (win + r) "compmgmt.msc" without quotes, look for the section of the Ethernet adapters and wireless (same place) select the wireless one and right click > properties.

Plus, we need to know the model of the laptop and wireless card, even if you brother is in the same room that not mean really anything, hardware could be different so the results are different.